# zookeeper.znode.parent mismatch exception

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have installed hadoop 2.2.0 & hbase-0.94.18 on ubuntu 12.04. When I try to run the command

```
create 't1','c1'
```

in hbase shell, I get the following error-

```
ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: 
Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. 
There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: @manu: Add comments to my answer with more details. I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things in no particular order:

- To start with, let the error display continue. It will try 7 times and then exit. Before it exits, it will show the name of exception occurring. Try to look it up. It probably says `MasterNotRunningException`.
- Verify that master is indeed running by doing `$sudo jps`. You should see an entry for `HMaster`. If not, start the hbase-master service.
- Assuming you're going for pseudo-distributed mode, you may also want to check your `/etc/hosts` to make sure that entries point to `127.0.0.1` and not `127.0.1.1`.
- For cloudera's installs, [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_20_5.html#topic_20_5) is a guide on how to setup HBase in pseudo-distributed mode. It also includes instructions to install hbase-master and zookeeper correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should check the file `hbase-site.xml` about `zookeeper.znode.parent` whether it's right. its default value is `/hbase`

Answer (score 1):

Mine was set by default to `/hbase-unsecure` (hbase-site.xml)